# Wildcard for an if else statement in sas data step

Tags: if-statement, sas, wildcard

I want to code a new variable from survey data based on a certain string, but including a wildcard for additional information before and after that string using a sas data step. The following code works matching the pattern at the beginning of the string

```
data survey_data;
    set final_data;
        if 'var1' =: 'this string' then var2 = 'Yes';
        else var2 = 'No';   
run;
```

But I'm not sure how to get it to match the pattern if it occurs in the middle of the string,  ':=:' does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `index` function :

```
data survey_data ;
  set final_data ;
  if index(var1,'this string') then var2 = 'Yes' ;
  else                              var2 = 'No' ;
run ;
```

The `INDEX` function returns a numeric value indicating the first character position in `var1` where `'this string'` was found. If it is not found `INDEX` returns zero. An `if` statement in SAS without a comparison operator (=><,eq,gt) resolves to true if it has a positive non-zero value, so:

```
if index(var1,'this string') then
```

is shorthand for:

```
if index(var1,'this string') > 0 then
```

SAS INDEX function > https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212242.htm

Comment: Any non-zero number is considered true. Not just positive. But the INDEX() function will not return a negative number.